# A trouble on `\mycaption`

Tags: captions

I am with a trouble on this project. I used `\mycaption`, but this gave me "**Figura 1**" in both figure and table.

Many thanks in advance for any light.

```
\documentclass{sciposter}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref,amsfonts,multirow,multicol}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{ascii}
\hypersetup{pdfpagelayout=SinglePage} %abre a pagina em modo simples
\hypersetup{pdfborder = {0 0 0}}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\usepackage{graphicx,colortbl}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{lipsum} %sugest\~ao de texto
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
%\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\geometry{paperwidth=83.96cm,paperheight=128.82cm,centering,
textwidth=75cm,textheight=117cm,left=2cm,top=2cm}
\pagestyle{plain}
\frenchspacing
%\usepackage{pstricks,pst-solides3d}
%\usepackage{tikz}

\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}
{\theoremstyle{stylename}
\newtheorem{exemplo}{Exemplo}}
{\theoremstyle{stylename}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definição}}
%%Transformando tudo em branco
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\textcolor{white}{\arabic{section}}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\textcolor{white}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%                mycaption                     %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \mycaption - replacement for \caption
% necessary, since in multicol-environment \figure and
% therefore \caption won't work
%\newcounter{figure}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\newcommand{\mycaption}[1]{
\vspace{0.6cm}
\begin{quote}
{{\sc Figura} \arabic{figure}: #1}
\end{quote}
\vspace{1cm}
}
%\addto\captionsbrazil{\renewcommand{\bibname}{\textcolor{white}{Refer\^encias}}}

%%Definindo cores
\definecolor{BoxCol}{gray}{0.1}

%%Define o caminho das figuras, vÃ¡lido somente para o comando \includegraphics
\graphicspath{{figuras/}}
%********************************************************************
%Teoremas
%\usepackage{theorem}
%\theorembodyfont{\normalfont\upshape}
%\newtheorem{ex}{Exemplo}
%\newenvironment{defn}[1][Defini\c{c}\~ao]{\textbf{#1:}\}%
%********************************************************************
%%Definindo de novos comandos

\newcommand{\tituloA}[1]{\emph{\textbf{\color{white}{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\tituloB}[1]{\emph{\textbf{\color{blue}{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}


%********************************************************************
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=30cm]{compartimental.jpg}
   \mycaption{Esquema dos Compartimentos dos humanos à
   esquerda e dos mosquitos à
   direita.}
\end{figure}



\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c } 

 \hline
 Parâmetros & Significado &Faixa utilizada \\ [0.5ex] 

 \hline 

\end{tabular}
\mycaption{ Valores utilizados nos parâmetros.}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your document, the `\mycaption` command is defined as

```
\newcommand{\mycaption}[1]{
    \vspace{0.6cm}
    \begin{quote}
    {{\sc Figura} \arabic{figure}: #1}
    \end{quote}
    \vspace{1cm}
}
```

Therefore, the `\mycaption` command will always write "Figura" when it is called, regardless of where it is used. In particular, if you use the `\mycaption` command in a `table` it will still write "Figura".

To solve the problem, you could copy the definition of `\mycaption`, and define say a `\mycaptiontable` command which would be the same as `\mycaption`, but with the word `Tabela` instead of the word `Figura` in its definition. So you could use the command

```
\newcommand{\mycaptiontable}[1]{
    \vspace{0.6cm}
    \begin{quote}
    {\textsc{Tabela} \arabic{table}: #1}
    \end{quote}
    \vspace{1cm}
}
```

(Note that I also changed `{\sc ...}` for `\textsc{...}` here. It doesn't have anything to do with your question, but in fact the commands `\sc`, `\bf` and `\it` are obsolete, and you should always use the `\textsc`, `\textbf` and `\textit` commands instead.)

This first approach works, and should give you the result you are looking for. However, I don't think it is the best solution. The package `caption` provides a `\captionof` command to insert captions outside of floats environments, so you could simply use this command. Here's a small example made from your document.

```
\documentclass{sciposter}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=sc]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image}
    \addtocounter{figure}{-1}
    \captionof{figure}{Esquema dos Compartimentos dos humanos à esquerda e dos mosquitos à direita.}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c c c} 
        \hline
        Parâmetros & Significado & Faixa utilizada \\[0.5ex] 
        \hline 
    \end{tabular}
    \addtocounter{table}{-1}
    \captionof{table}{Valores utilizados nos parâmetros.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This code produces:
[image]

I think I should make two remarks about this last example.

1. The `figure` environment and the `\captionof{figure}` command both increase the `figure` counter by 1. So if we want the `figure` counter to be increased only by 1 overall, we have to add `\addtocounter{figure}{-1}` before the `\caption{figure}` is called. The same situation happens with the table.
2. For the caption labels `Figura` and `Tabela` to be written in small caps, I changed the option `labelfont=bf` for `labelfont=sc` when the `caption` package is loaded.

Comment: Many thanks, Vincent!